# Ajax not getting api data but on browser api is working

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api

My code does not get any output please help. My code so far:

```
$.ajax({

    url: "http://cricketapi.herokuapp.com/getMatches",
    crossOrigin: true,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (data) {
        alert("heyy succes");
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
        alert("error");
    }                
});
```

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow we are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to try and help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried, a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember that a large part of coding is troubleshooting and it’s important to develop this skill.

Comment: your code do get an output: https://codepen.io/spmsupun/pen/bKMdWr